# R: Adding a new column that's element is a vector of previous elements

Tags: r, vector

I have a datatable df1 and I want to add a new column. The column's elements are vectors and each vector has inside the elements of the row.
so right now I should have

```
column1|column2|column3|
    3      | 4 |NA
    3      | 6 |NA
    5      | 4 |NA
```

but what I want is this.

```
column1|column2|column3|vec
    3      | 4 |NA|c(3,4)
    3      | 6 |NA|c(3,6)
    5      | 4 |NA|c(5,4)
```

I tried using `unname(unlist(df1))` and then

```
df1$vec <- df1$vec[!is.na(df1$vec)]
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: `df1$vec <- apply(df1, 1, function(x)list(x[!is.na(x)]))`?

Comment: it gives me for example list(c("3","4"))

Comment: Please give a better example. Right now the end result is just the input without "vec" column

Comment: Please provide `dput(head(df1))`

Comment: @John.Doh I see. What about `m <- row(df1);m[is.na(df1)] <- NA;df1$vec <- unname(split(as.matrix(df1), m))` then?